# What is the difference between a lomo and a polaroid?

Tags: polaroid, lomo

I saw Fuji Instax 210 Wide Camera while looking for a good Polaroid and noticed that it behaves like a polaroid in a sense that you can print the picture right away. Is it both a lomo and a polaroid?

Comment: Welcome Randell. No need to apologize for questions here — that's what the site is for. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lomo and Polaroid are both brands with products in the photography field -- Polaroid are known for their instant cameras, with the name becoming synonymous for a camera that produces photographs instantly. Lomo are a Russian company that have also made cameras, but have become more well known recently following marketing by Lomography who have sole rights for distribution of their cameras outside Russia; their cameras are typically 35mm film cameras, and tend to be fairly low-tech (so no options like auto-focus, or wind on) but are sometimes specialised in a single way (for example, there is a fisheye camera).

Fujifilm is another brand, so that Fujifilm Instax 210 is neither a lomo or a polaroid - it just shares attributes that made those brands popular (i.e. specialised for a single purpose, and providing instant prints)